# MySQL Select parents and children

Tags: mysql, parent, children

I'm having troubles with this MySQL query. Would you be so kind to help me out?

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `time` (
  `id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `activity` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `decimalTime` float NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
);
```

`time.parent` is another item in the `time` table. I want to select all time items, and the children should be listed directly after their parent is listed.

So for example:

```
ID         PARENT
1          NULL
2          NULL
3          NULL
4          2
5          1
```

Should be listed as following:

```
ID         PARENT
1          NULL
5          1
2          NULL
4          2
3          NULL
```

So far I tried this:

```
SELECT a.title, parent.user, parent.activity, parent.time, parent.decimalTime, parent.date, child.parent,
CASE 
    WHEN (child.parent IS NOT NULL) THEN child.id
    ELSE parent.id
END AS id
FROM time AS parent
     LEFT JOIN time AS child 
     ON child.parent = parent.id
     LEFT JOIN activity AS a
     ON child.activity = a.id OR parent.activity = a.id
WHERE parent.parent IS NULL
ORDER BY parent.id, child.id
```

The problem is that I can't get it to give out the correct ids. 
[This happens when I run the command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzOPF.png)

Could you point out where my mistake is, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you have more rows per "time" rows in the activy table, so the join multiplies your results by that number.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand what you mean. My time table has 8 items and only 8 items get selected. I don't have items appearing multiple times. [SELECT *](http://upload.boimel.net/2016-02-08_21-01-09_1454961669.PNG) vs [my command](http://upload.boimel.net/2016-02-08_21-02-44_1454961764.PNG)

Comment: In you screenshot I can see 11 items selected